# Can I use java.time.LocalDate in Spark Dataframe udf?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, java-time

I have to call a method which takes the `java.time.LocalDate` as input parameter.

I am doing in Spark Dataframe, and I call the method in udf.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.LocalDate

val df = Seq((1, "2018-02-11T09:40:00+08:00")).toDF("id", "date_time")
df.show

+---+-------------------------+
|id |date_time                |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |2018-02-11T09:40:00+08:00|
+---+-------------------------+

def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
val dateTime = "2018-06-10T09:30:00+02:00"
def complexMethod(d: LocalDate) = {
  d
  // do really complex thing
  // imagine there could be many other input params, localDate is just the one blocking here
}
```

I try to do:

```
val transformer = udf((dateTime: String) => {
  val localDate = ZonedDateTime.from(formatter.parse(dateTime)).toLocalDate;
  complexMethod(localDate)
})

df.withColumn("transformed", transformer(col("date_time"))).show
```

It will have error:

```
// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type java.time.LocalDate is not supported
```

I have to pass `java.time.LocalDate` as input to `complexMethod` (imagine this `complexMethod` is from another lib), and call it in udf. The error seems to mean that `java.time.LocalDate` is not allowed in udf.

1. What is the reason that `java.time.LocalDate` is not allowed?
2. How can I call `complexMethod` in udf?
3. If it's really not possible, what is the best way to call `complexMethod`? Use RDD, Dataset?

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate` is not supported up to `Spark 2.2`. You will have to convert `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Hi @SašaZejnilović Thanks for the comment, I tried Spark 2.4, I have the same error. I could use `java.sql.Date` if I'm handling the date time only, but let's say I'm doing more than that, calling an api that has many input params and date is only one of the many. The question is more to understand the reason behind, why is it not supported? What does it mean?